# How do you change the extent of a clipped raster layer in qgis to be the mbb?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, extents

I have a raster layer that I have clipped using a polygon in qgis. The extent of the raster layer did not change.
How do I update the extent of my raster layer so that it is the minimum bounding box of my clipping?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! If you can go back to the clipping process (`Clipper`),  there is an option `Crop the extent of the target dataset to the extent of the cutline` which appears when you choose `Mask layer` clipping mode.

Answer (score 2):

To change the extent of raster,

(1) SAGA tools from `Processing Toolbox`can fit the raster extent to the clipped image.

*Step 1*: **Reclassify** the area outside of the image from *zero* to *nodata*

First, activate `Processing Tools | SAGA | Raster Tools | Reclassify values`

Options can be set as:

- `Grid`: your raster file
- `Method`: single       (default)
- `old value`: 0.000000  (default)
- `new value`: -99999
- Check `replace no data values` checkbox
- `new value for no data values`: -99999
- Uncheck `replace other values`

and [Run]

*Step 2*: **Crop to data**

Then next tool is `Processing Tools | SAGA | Raster Tools | Crop to data`

- Input layer: Reclassified layer

and [Run]

---

However, if you can go back to the clipping process (Clipper), you would get an optimized extent, and the above steps are unnecessary.

(2)  Clipper

- Choose Mask layer clipping mode
- Assign a polygon as Mask
- Select an option `Crop the extent of the target dataset to the extent of the cutline`